# Bootstrap 5 - Can expand but not collapse navbar

Tags: bootstrap-5

I used to work with an earlier version of Bootstrap but am trying to get into the current version 5.3.0. I'm using template code which I've updated to current Bootstrap version.

I'm currently trying to get the navbar working but it only does half-way; In small-screen I can expand the navbar, but the toggler button doesn't work when I want to collapse the navbar again. I've been up and down the code but feel kind of snowblind as I can't see what's wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
    <title>StrindbergAppen</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Laddar extern styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Laddar script för att få tillgång till ikoner för menyknapparna -->  
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>

    <script>
        /* ----- Javascript for SPA - Single Page Application logic ----- */
        // Help function that shows page with id page+p and hides all other pages
        function showPage(p) {
            // Step 1 - Hide all pages
            pageArr = document.getElementsByClassName("page");
            for (let i = 0; i < pageArr.length; i++) {
                let page = pageArr[i];
                page.style.display = "none";
            }
            // Step 2 - Show the selected page
            document.getElementById("page" + p).style.display = "block";
 
            // Step 3 - Make all navbar buttons inactive 
            let btnArr = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-btn");
            for (let i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) {
                let btn = btnArr[i];
                btn.classList.remove("active");
            }
 
            // Step 4 - Make page all navbar buttons with class nav+p active
            btnArr = document.getElementsByClassName("nav" + p);
            for (let i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) {
                let btn = btnArr[i];
                btn.classList.add("active");
            }
        }
        /* -----  ----- */
 
        // Init function. Here we can put code that is needed to initialize our prototype.
        function initPrototype() {
            // For example, when using sound or sensors this becomes important.
            console.log("==> Prototype init started.");
 
            // Show the landingpage/startpage
            showPage(1);
        }
    </script>

</head>
 
<body onload="showPage(0);">
    <!-- Page0 is needed for initPrototype() function. DON'T REMOVE! -->
    <!-- Page0 is needed for initPrototype() function. DON'T REMOVE! -->
    <div id="page0" class="page">
        <div class="prototype-start-page">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="initPrototype();">Start prototype</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page0 is needed for initPrototype() function. DON'T REMOVE! -->
    <!-- Page0 is needed for initPrototype() function. DON'T REMOVE! -->
    <!-- alla sidor -->
    <!-- Nya sidor måste ha klassen 'page' och ett id 'pageX', där X måste vara ett unikt nummer på sidan,
         och ha HTML-strukturen:

        <div id="pageX" class="page">
            Nya sidans HTML-innehåll. Glöm inte att ta med menyn.
        </div>

        I exemplet har vi tre sidor för app-prototypen, page1, page2 och page3, så en naturlig nästa sida vore page4:

        <div id="page4" class="page">
            Nya sidans HTML-innehåll. Glöm inte att ta med menyn och lägga till ett 4e menyalternativ.
        </div>

        För att javascriptet som sköter sidnavigeringen skall fungera krävas att meny-knapparna har klasserna
        'navbar-btn' och 'navX', där X är nummret för sidan som meny-knappen öppnar. Vi måste också ange nummret
        på sidan som skall öppnas av meny-knappen genom att använda '4' som parameter till funktionen 'showPage();'

        T ex, för att lägga till en meny-knapp för 'page4' så skulle vi skapa följande knapp:
        <button class="nav4 nav3 btn navbar-btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="showPage(4);">Go to page 4</button>

        Klassen navbar__btn--active innehåller stylingen för det menyalternativ som är aktivt.
    -->

    <div id="page1" class="page">
        <!-- Top bar -->
        <div class="top-app-bar">
            <div>
                <i class="icon-mob-size" data-feather="home" onclick="showPage(1)">
                </i>
                <span class="top-nav-headline">StrindbergAppen</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">StrindbergAppen</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bilder på August Strindberg</a>
                        </li>
                        
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Betygsätt Strindberg</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Om Strindbergappen</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- End of Navbar! -->
        <div>
            <!-- page content -->
            <h1>August Strindberg</h1>
            <picture>
                <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="./img/hero/hero_medium.jpg">
                <source media="(min-width: 1280px)" srcset="./img/hero/hero_large.jpg">
                <img src="./img/hero/hero_small.jpg" alt="Gatubild från sekelskiftets Stockholm" style="width:100%;">
            </picture>
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Biografi</h2>
                <picture class="left-align">
                    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="./img/poet/poet_250x500.jpg, ./img/poet/poet_250x500@2.jpg 2x">
                    <source media="(min-width: 375px)" srcset="./img/poet/poet_125x250.jpg, ./img/poet/poet_250x500.jpg 2x">
                    <img class="left-align" src="./img/poet/poet_250x500.jpg" alt="August Strindberg by Robert Roesler, circa 1881">
                </picture>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime saepe praesentium error placeat ullam tempore
                    magni enim, debitis aliquam mollitia similique ipsa ipsum sunt ratione natus expedita cumque repellendus
                    provident?
                    Tempore itaque nostrum eligendi deleniti dolores ipsam repudiandae ipsum culpa exercitationem harum.
                    Distinctio aliquam ducimus illo modi nihil quis minus ullam rerum sapiente doloribus! Fugit, provident?
                    Voluptate nemo excepturi ducimus.
                    Corrupti accusantium perspiciatis ducimus vitae similique deserunt repellendus laudantium numquam velit
                    excepturi quidem, molestiae quos, eveniet ut. Unde consequatur ad repellat, natus maiores recusandae facilis
                    laboriosam doloremque maxime eveniet aliquid?
                    Aperiam voluptates quibusdam delectus quasi cum nobis nostrum ratione architecto fugiat exercitationem?
                    Animi aliquid, quaerat placeat voluptatem tempore mollitia assumenda eaque quae officiis amet tempora,
                    reprehenderit cumque? Quod, quasi accusantium.
                    Debitis tenetur atque temporibus ratione totam optio, illum officia provident eos repellat accusamus
                    excepturi maxime veniam neque nobis odio inventore sit laborum, dolorum perspiciatis. Eligendi non
                    architecto repellat inventore nam.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="page2" class="page">
        <!-- navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <button class="nav1 navbar-btn btn btn-primary active" type="button" onclick="showPage(1);">Go to page 1</button>
            <button class="nav2 navbar-btn btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="showPage(2);">Go to page2</button>
            <button class="nav3 navbar-btn btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="showPage(3);">Go to page3</button>
        </nav>
        <!-- page content -->
        <h1>Example page 2</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium maxime expedita culpa? Nostrum
            perspiciatis perferendis dolore atque fuga inventore blanditiis! Minus mollitia dolorum nesciunt in magni
            necessitatibus minima porro officia.
            Corrupti fuga maiores aut eligendi id quasi necessitatibus. A nihil, repellendus quia dolores magnam
            temporibus cum molestiae debitis. Eveniet, dolor voluptates? Officiis rerum aliquid repellendus quia dolore
            omnis optio cum.
            Beatae illum est et sint hic magnam, dignissimos quos excepturi nihil harum minus deserunt odio deleniti
            praesentium eum adipisci fuga sequi porro, dolore cupiditate eligendi rerum distinctio reiciendis?
            Blanditiis, incidunt.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="page3" class="page">
        <!-- navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <button class="nav1 navbar-btn btn btn-primary active" type="button" onclick="showPage(1);">Go to page 1</button>
            <button class="nav2 navbar-btn btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="showPage(2);">Go to page2</button>
            <button class="nav3 navbar-btn btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="showPage(3);">Go to page3</button>
        </nav>
        <!-- page content -->
        <h1>Example page 3</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae explicabo tempora ullam cumque, obcaecati
            aut sed inventore excepturi, voluptatibus ratione laborum incidunt quod. Cum quis eos adipisci consequatur
            ipsa. Sed!
            Voluptatum voluptas sunt tenetur porro maiores veritatis, ipsam libero? Nesciunt ea quas iusto ducimus
            suscipit eos quibusdam. Doloremque cum fugiat, tempora qui temporibus delectus. Fuga quaerat accusamus non
            iusto delectus.
            Esse a sit et nobis ducimus sint, porro, quod accusamus exercitationem voluptatum placeat sed. Soluta,
            blanditiis aliquam consectetur rem aliquid itaque tempore ea corporis recusandae? Dignissimos sit expedita
            commodi quibusdam.
            Illo voluptates culpa assumenda recusandae explicabo ab pariatur? Temporibus qui dolorum expedita culpa
            animi eligendi pariatur fuga dolorem ipsum, alias hic unde, nulla tenetur odio saepe enim aut ratione
            laboriosam!
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      feather.replace()
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...............................
**Edit**: Looks like you don't need to have it in the body, but the fact that you have the same line twice is what is giving you the issue. Deleting the specified line will solve your issue.
...............................

I have solved your problem. You are not implementing Bootstrap 5 properly. You have two instances of this line: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`. Delete them both but save the line to your clipboard. Then paste one **inside of the body**.

According to the documentation at getbootstrap.com, the script should be at the end of the **body**, *not* in **head**.

It will work after you move that line.

Comment: Thank you. I should have caught that of course, but had been sitting with code for too long, so I couldn't see the forest for all the trees, I guess.